# Making a followers system

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to make an app with followers and I am having some trouble to see in the view the people that i am following

this is the user model :

```
public function books(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Book', 'book_id');
    }

    public function follows() {
        return $this->hasMany(Follow::class);
    }
    public function isFollowing($target_id)
    {
        return (bool)$this->follows()->where('target_id', $target_id)->first(['id']);
    }
```

and this is the follow model

```
class Follow extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['target_id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

this is the FollowController

```
public function follow(User $user)
    {
        if (!Auth::user()->isFollowing($user->id)) {
            // Create a new follow instance for the authenticated user
            Auth::user()->follows()->create([
                'target_id' => $user->id,
            ]);

            return back()->with('success', 'You are now friends with '. $user->name);
        } else {
            return back()->with('error', 'You are already following this person');
        }

    }
```

and this is the userController

```
public function showOwnProfile()
    {
      $usuarioLog=Auth::user();

      $user = User::find($usuarioLog->id);
      $follow=Follow::where("target_id","=",$usuarioLog["id"] )->get();
      $following=Follow::where("user_id","=",$usuarioLog["id"] )->get();


      $userBooks = Book::where('user_id', '=', $usuarioLog["id"])->get();
      $usuarioLog=Auth::user();
      $myBooks=Book::where("user_id","=","$usuarioLog->id")->get();



      $vacLibros=compact("userBooks");
      $vacUser = compact('user', 'follow','following','myBooks','usuarioLog');

      return view("/profile", $vacLibros, $vacUser);
    }
```

and finally the view (where I want to visualize the people that i am following)

```
<h1>lista de seguidos</h1>

   @forelse ($following as $following_user) //??????

   <p> <a style="color:black; font-weight:bolder"  href="/normalProfile/{{$following_user}}"> {{//?????}}</a></p>

   @empty
   <p> No sigues a nadie</p>
   @endforelse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the column in the `{{}}` put what you're calling column here

```
<p> <a style="color:black; font-weight:bolder" href="/normalProfile/{{$following_user->column}}"> {{//?????}}</a></p>
```

Since I don't know what your column name is I just put column so you edit that one.

I'm not knowledgable in relationship query but try this:

```
$following=Follow::where("user_id","=",$usuarioLog["id"] )
->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'follow.target_id')
->select('follow.*','users.*')->get();
```

Comment: what column are you refeering? The follow table has Id, user_id and target_id. But if I put target_id (that is what i want) I just get a number. I don't know if I am missing a relation or something. The number of Target_id reefers to a User, and I want to see the name of that user. but i don't know how

Comment: you only input $following_user you didn't put what column you want to call. You need to specify it because its gonna call what you need its a set of collection that's why you need to call it

Comment: If i put {{$following_user->target_id}} i get target_id, which is a number, that is refeering to a user. i want the name of the user, not a number. I don't know how to access the name of the user with that number.

Comment: what is the column name of the name of user?

Comment: user has a column named 'name' (if that is the question)

Comment: then its `$following_user->user()->name` or `$following_user->user->name`

Comment: That gives the name of the user that is being followed instead of the user that he or she is being followed by. In table terms: it gives it user_id instead of the target_id. Maybe i need to build another function that relates specifically to target_id? idk

Comment: What do you mean? You want to visualize the user that being followed means the one who's following who's logged in right? your following queries getting all the user followed right? If not then you need to change the query.

Comment: I want the person who is logged, to be able to see a list with all the people that he is following. I also think that i should modify the query, but I am having some trouble to think it through

Comment: When the user follow someone where you are putting the id of the user and where are you putting the id of its following

Comment: in a table called Follows. there i have user_id which is the user that is following and target_id, which is the user that is being followed

Comment: $follow=Follow::where("target_id","=",$usuarioLog["id"] )->get();
$following=Follow::where("user_id","=",$usuarioLog["id"] )->get();

Comment: Again, it shows the name of the logged person, instead of the people that he follows ):

Comment: You should call `$following_user->name` not the one I answer earlier